# Pushing an object to an array is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've got the following problem.

```
let putUsernames = async (entry) => {
    let playerData = [];

    await entry.messages.forEach(async (log, index) => {
        let username;

        playerData.forEach((data) => {
            if (data.uuid == log.uuid) {
                username = data.username;
            }
        });

        if (!username) {
            let data = await PlayerSchema.schema.findOne({ uuid: log.uuid }).exec();
            if (data) {
                data = data.toObject();
                username = data.username;
            }

            console.log("uuid: " + log.uuid);
            console.log("username: " + username);

            playerData.push({
                uuid: log.uuid,
                username
            });
        }

        console.log(username);

        entry.messages[index].username = username;
    });

    return entry;
};
```

With this function I'm trying to get the usernames from the mongo database which is equal with the uuid from the entry log.
The entry log looks like this:

```
{
   "_id":"5df695a54df4b838c380643b",
   "id":"U8HJ08J",
   "date":1576441253139,
  "messages":[
      {
         "uuid":"uuid1",
         "message":"Hello!",
         "date":1576440196224
      },
      {
         "uuid":"uuid2",
         "message":"Hello there",
         "date":1576440202681
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, what I'm trying at the moment is to push the usernames into the message objects:

```
"messages":[
      {
         "uuid":"uuid1",
         "message":"Hello!",
         "date":1576440196224,
         "username": "username1"
      },
      {
         "uuid":"uuid2",
         "message":"Hello there",
         "date":1576440202681,
         "username": "username2"
      }
   ]
```

At the same I'm trying to push the usernames into playerData so that I don't always have to access the mongo database but it seems to be that the pushing it not working as I want.

console.log("uuid: " + log.uuid); and console.log("username: " + username); is working normally and they're also outputting the correct data, but entry.messages[index].username = username; is not working, so that means the entry is the same as the beginning :(

Is there anyone who has any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just solved the problem, I just used for instead of forEach

```
let putUsernames = async (entry) => {
    let playerData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < entry.messages.length; i++) {
        let username;

        playerData.forEach((data) => {
            if (data.uuid == entry.messages[i].uuid) {
                username = data.username;
            }
        });

        if (!username) {
            let data = await PlayerSchema.schema.findOne({ uuid: entry.messages[i].uuid }).exec();
            if (data) {
                data = data.toObject();
                username = data.username;
            }

            playerData.push({
                uuid: entry.messages[i].uuid,
                username
            });
        }
        entry.messages[i].username = username;
    }

    return entry;
};
```